# Unwanted Blue color lines around my viewcontroller and storyboard items

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am having Xcode 7.3 and facing an issue of Blue lines around my viewcontroller and storyboard items as shown in attached image. I reinstalled my xcode twice but this issue ain't fix. Any help from you will be appreciated.

[image: What is the reason behind these blue lines?]

Comment: are you using size classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can uncheck Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles of Xcode's menu.

[image]

Comment: hi, that solved it for you completly? I can remove them also like this, but when I switch to some other file and switch back to the storyboard, the lines appear again. Is smt wrong with the storyboard or is that a setting ?

Answer (score 4):

uncheck shoe Bounds Rectangles under Editor menu
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have selected "Show Bounds Rectangles" in Editor->Canvas, just deselect it.
[image]

Comment: it's Done! Thanks anyways.